# What parameters limit the speed of LASER operation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, semiconductor-physics, laser

What parameters limit the speed of LASER operation and how can we overcome them to
obtain ultrafast laser sources.

Comment: What do you mean by speed? And we already have ultrafast sources...

Comment: Do you mean the speed of switching a laser on and off?  The maximum modulation rate?